# Session_End code on browser close

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a method I need to run on Session_end. Is there any way I can ensure the code runs when a user closes his browser? This may be a dup queston. I saw one response doing a call to ajax unload or something, but I don't want this to fire everytime a user navigates away from a page, just when they close their browser.

Thanks,
~ck

Comment: ASP.NET Session state has nothing to do with when or if the user closes the browser.

Comment: Also note that Session_End will only fire In-Proc mode

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You can't control user's browser. The AJAX solution you mentioned is the closest you can achieve (without a plugin/custom client.) Imagine some Web site could track every time you opened and closed your browser window. Don't you think it would be a privacy issue?

The truth lies in the stateless nature of HTTP. The Web server is out of the picture as soon as it finishes sending the response to the client. After that, all you can rely on is a client side script (which only executes because the client wants it to; and it can easily choose not to run scripts.)

Answer (score 2):

Session_end is unreliable.  No matter what you do.

Session_end only fires when you are using inprocess session.  If you are using a session state server or SQL session, session_end does not fire.

When using in process session, session_end only fires if you have stored something in session.  If you aren't using session, session_end will never fire.

If you are using session and the user closes the browser, session_end will fire when the users session times out.  While it will have some of the same settings as the original session, this event will not be tied to a browser since it is the worker process detecting the session timeout and firing the session_end process.

Comment: If so, it is not between the browser and the server. Once a session ended we can rely on the Session_end to fire somewhere in the near future. So, if I have a static int of counter, I can count how many sessions are active still.

Comment: That counter will typically be on the high side. It will include sessions from users who have closed their browser but their session has not yet timed out.

Comment: If you could please explain on "High side". In addition, i am currently building a Chat application on my site and would like to have a static list of users so I could retrieve all names and IDs. So, knowing a little bit later that the user has signed off is not that bad. no?

Comment: @Bergkamp, sounds like you are treating session_end as a log off. It is not designed to be that; it is something very different. Search the web for "session_end not firing" to get an idea of the issues. And whether or not knowing a bit later that the user has signed off is an issue depends upon the usage. Given that, IMO, it is very bad in a chat app.

Comment: I never planned for that. I was just thinking to myself what if the user just closed his browser and havent logged off, I need to take him off the "OnlineUsers" List. That way, I can check on Session_End if the Session is still active, if so I just go to the List and set him as offline with the Session["accountId"]