# How to detect when sessions expire in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session, detect

I want to track if users loout or their session expire. I need to k now exactly when their session expired (within +/- 5 min). Right now if a users leaves the page open in the browser and returns after a day, I will know it expired when he tries to do something after a day- but in reality the session expired after say an hour of inactivity.

I want to have a script run every 5 minutes on the server and check which sessions are expired and detect them and then log the expiration time in a db.
How do I have a script run continuously with such short intervals on the server?
What exactly does the script do?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 10):

In your `global.asax`, you can capture the `Session_End` event. See this question for further details:

- [How to handle session end in global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621744/how-to-handle-session-end-in-global-asax)

Note that a five minute timeout is not easily possible, since you have to wait for the session to expire (= usually 20 min.) before you can detect the inactivity. Thus, if you really need the short interval, you'd need to

- [reduce the Session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648992/session-timeout-in-asp-net) to five minutes.

On the other hand, you also need to

- make sure that five minutes of inactivity with an open browser does not cause the session to be abandoned (unless you want your users to lose their session when they leave the computer to get a cup of coffee). Such an "automatic keepalive" can be implemented, for example, by [using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/Reconnect.aspx).

Comment: This only works if the SessionState is set to InProc. Another SO question with different details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262867/session-end-code-on-browser-close

Comment: Might also be worth noting that if you check for the existence of a Session it will reset it's timeout timer if it exists...

Comment: @hunter, any more info on this? :-)

Comment: @hunter yeah, I wasn't aware of it being reset

Comment: If you touch an item in the Session and it is set to expire it will reset it's timer. Checking if it `== null` will cause it to reset.