# handle timeout of session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

I was wondering it's there a way to configure the application in the web.config or somewhere to handle the time out of a session. What I want to achieve is go to some controller and save the datetime and some other values of my session which are in sessions variable before are setting null because the session  get's the timeout

Comment: Do you have a database where you could store this session state? Does each user authenticate before these state values are created? I'm thinking you could store the values so that if session expires you can look them-up again based on user creds.

Comment: yeap, actually a have a table in my data base that stores the datetime when the user logon, but if the session expires i can't handle this moment before the application set in null

Comment: Can you try session_end in global.asax?

Comment: but the session variable are going to have value??. Remember I want handle before I lost the values

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if its the same in MVC but in ye olde asp.net I had an application that needed to log when someones session timed out and I did it in the Global.asax.cs file in the Session_End

```
if (Session == null || Session["logout-clicked"] != null) return;
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Session["session.start"];
new EventLog()
{
    EventLogType = EventLogType.SessionTimedOut,
    UserId = ((UserObject)Session["UserSession"]).Id,
    DateStamp = DateTime.Now,
    LogData = "logged in for: " + (Int32)ts.TotalHours + "hrs " + ts.Minutes + "mins",
    CachedName = ((UserObject)Session["UserSession"]).Name
}.Save();
```

Obviously you'll have to set up some of those session variables in your login method (if you want that kind of information, like total logged in time/session time) and you'll probably have your own methods to save whatever data it is you need to save... but hopefully that might inspire a few ideas?

I have a "logout-clicked" session variable (set when you click on logout) because when the user clicks on logout it will have a different log and Session_End is called after you call Session.Abandon() so I needed to make sure it didnt log a logout followed by a session timeout.

Comment: Session_End has limitations. First and most importantly, it only works when using InProc session management. Secondly, depending on what you are storing, you could get inaccurate data based on users who close their browsers. You won't be able to tell the difference between users that timed out on the site and users that closed the browser window. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262867/session-end-code-on-browser-close